# What do you call a sibling who keeps calling 'mom?'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

That younger sibling who shouts 'mom' when you tease them. You hit or about to him/her and he/she yells 'mom' or 'dad.'

Comment: I am not really sure about my answer but I would say "wimp". http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/wimp 
I need to know more about the situation. You can check its synonyms.

Comment: You could use **crybaby**

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're after a ***tattletale***:

> a child who tells a parent, teacher, etc., about something bad or wrong that another child has done : a child who tattles on another child - *[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tattletale)*

Answer (score 0):

English is not my native but a word "sissy" springs to mind, mostly for a boy behaving like that.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sissy

Comment: ... but both wimp or sissy do not necessarily apply to a **sibling** (I've just re-read the question :) ), they are universal.